# Finding sequence of group generators that yields group element

Tags: permutation, group-theory

Here is my permutation group that acts on lists of length 4, defined in terms of four generators:

```
permGroup = PermutationGroup[{Cycles[{{1, 3}, {2, 4}}], 
                Cycles[{{1, 2}}], Cycles[{{3, 4}}], Cycles[{{2, 4}}]}]
```

Given a list of four entires out of order, I can get the permutation required using `FindPermutation` or the position of the element in the group using `GroupElementPosition`:

```
outOfOrderExample = {3,1,2,4};

GroupElementPosition[permGroup, FindPermutation[outOfOrderExample,{1,2,3,4}]]
(*13*)
```

But, how do I get the precise sequence of group generators that when multiplied together puts the list `outOfOrderExample` back in order?  Obviously, **the answer is not unique**.  I just need any of the shortest answer.

An acceptable answer would be a list of numbers identifying the generators in `permGroup`, such as `{2, 3, 4, 3}` for this example.  You can check the answer is correct by doing something like

```
Permute[outOfOrderExample,
   PermutationProduct@@First[permGroup][[{2, 3, 4, 3}]]]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`GroupElementToWord`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupElementToWord.html). There are some examples in the documentation, especially in the *Neat Examples* section which mentions Rubik's cube.

Below I express the permutation that takes `{3,1,2,4}` to `{1,2,3,4}` in terms of a 'word' or sequence of the group generators (and their inverses).

```
perms = {
  Cycles[{{1, 3}, {2, 4}}],
  Cycles[{{1, 2}}],
  Cycles[{{3, 4}}],
  Cycles[{{2, 4}}]
};

permGroup = PermutationGroup[perms];
generators = GroupGenerators[permGroup];

outOfOrderExample = {3, 1, 2, 4};
reversePerm = FindPermutation[outOfOrderExample, Sort@outOfOrderExample];
GroupElementQ[permGroup, reversePerm]
ge2word = GroupElementToWord[permGroup, reversePerm];
(** result: {-4, 3,-1} - e.g 3 means apply perm 3,
  while -4 means apply inverse of perm 4 **)

reversePermSequence = 
  If[Positive@#, Identity, InversePermutation][
     generators[[Abs[#]]]] & /@ ge2word;

Fold[Permute, outOfOrderExample, reversePermSequence]
(*result {1,2,3,4}*)
```

Comment: Thank you!  I did not know what the function was called.  To be clear, -4 even though inverse of perm 4, is the same as 4 because it is self inverse.  Right?

Comment: @QuantumDot Yes the language of group theory and most modern algebra is needlessly byzantine. And yes, it just so happens that `InversePermutation[perms[[4]]]` is the same as `perms[[4]]`.

Comment: I made some minor edits which uses the group generators instead of the original perms and fixes the order, since I noticed a bug when trying some different groups. I realize the generators  are the same, but this is just so anybody passing by with a different set of perms finds this useful.